# Start different button timers in android

Tags: android

My app has several buttons which their text on them is a counter. Each button with a different counter. I want to start whichever i want 2 independently. My problem is that when i press one button all the other button counter start. So i have many buttons to start a counter when just one is pressed. I know there are many lol apps for this but i want to practice on coding android:P I know the problem is on the onTick method. But i dont know how to call many onTick methods one for each button, or have if/switch statements inside the onTick. Anyone knows how can i do this?

Thank u for your time

```
public class TimersActivity extends Activity {

Button wraith, wolf, golem, blue_golem, red_golem, enemy_wraith, enemy_wolf, enemy_golem, enemy_blue_golem, enemy_red_golem, dragon, baron;

final MyCounter wraithTimer = new MyCounter(50000,100, wraith);
final MyCounter enemy_wraithTimer = new MyCounter(50000,100, wolf);

final MyCounter wolfTimer = new MyCounter(60000,100, null);
final MyCounter enemy_wolfTimer = new MyCounter(60000,100, null);
final MyCounter golemTimer = new MyCounter(60000,100, null);
final MyCounter enemy_golemTimer = new MyCounter(60000,100, null);
final MyCounter blue_golemTimer = new MyCounter(300000,100, null);
final MyCounter enemy_blue_golemTimer = new MyCounter(300000,100, null);
final MyCounter red_golemTimer = new MyCounter(300000,100, null);
final MyCounter enemy_red_golemTimer = new MyCounter(300000,100, null);
final MyCounter dragonTimer = new MyCounter(360000,100, null);
final MyCounter baronTimer = new MyCounter(420000,100, null);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timers);

        wraith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wraiths);
        wolf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wolfs);
        golem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.golems);
        blue_golem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.blue_golem);
        red_golem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.redbuff_creep);
        enemy_wraith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enemy_wraiths);
        enemy_wolf = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enemy_wolfs);
        enemy_golem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enemy_golems);
        enemy_blue_golem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enemy_blue_golem);
        enemy_red_golem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enemy_redbuff_creep);
        dragon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dragon);
        baron = (Button)findViewById(R.id.baron);

        wraith.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wraithTimer.start();
            }
        });

    }

    public enum buttons{wraith,wolf};
    public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer{



        public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, Button nam) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }


        public void onFinish() {
            wraith.setText("DONE");

        }
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished, buttons names) {

            switch(names){

            case wraith: 
                wraith.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000)+"");
                break;
            case wolf: 
                 wolf.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000)+"");
                 break;         
            }

        }


        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use Enums in the MyCounter class.

Simply assign it in the constructor, then in the onTick() method, use a switch with the enum as parameter.

---

edit:

using the enum in the constructor would mean using this code in the initializers:

```
final MyCounter <name>Timer = new MyCounter(x0000, 100, buttons.wraith);
```

In your MyCounter class add a private field in which you store the enum like so:

```
private buttons button;
```

and in your constructor, assign the enum:

```
public MyCounter(long millisInFutre, long countdownInterval, buttons name) {
    super(millisInFutre, countdownInterval);
    this.button = name;
}
```

then the onTick method should be called as usual:

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    switch(button) {
    case buttons.wraith:
        wraith.setText(...);
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope you'll finish this :)

Comment: Ill edit on my initial coding in my top post how my class is now. I get errors on the MyCounter class. The solutions eclipse give me is to make another onTick method without the buttons in the parameters. And the other solution is to make the class abstract. Both solutions give me more errors.

Comment: @lantonis don't forget to mark an answer if the question is answered :).

Comment: done. Didnt know i have to do that:P Its the green tick on the left of your answer right?

Comment: Yes, it's the green tick :). To be honest it isn't mandatory, but it's definately encouraged.